# multiple joins, each with IN statement returns too many results

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with building `mysql` query so it returns right results. Idea is that i need to fetch data from main table but some of the fields are only references to other tables where also record exists in various languages.

so example code is:

```
SELECT cars.model
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN parts ON parts.id = cars.partId AND parts.language IN ('en', 'de')
LEFT JOIN interior ON interior.id = cars.interiorId AND interior.language IN ('en', 'de')
LEFT JOIN exterior ON exterior.id = cars.exteriorId AND exterior.language IN ('en', 'de')
LEFT JOIN wheels ON wheels.id = cars.wheelId AND wheels.language IN ('en', 'de')
LEFT JOIN extra ON extra.id = cars.extraId AND extra.language IN ('en', 'de')
WHERE cars.id IN ('72727272') AND cars.source = 1
```

What i need is two results from query (one in english and one in german), instead i am getting 24 results. They are in various configuration of languages.

I tried adding:

- `GROUP BY ...` but its not working.
- `DISTINCT` same as above

Maybe someone knows some tricks on how to deal with this kind of situation (at worst case i can execute query twice for each language but its extremely slow).

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT cards.model`

Comment: unfortunately results are still 24

Comment: could you paste image of  results as well. It might help in knowing the problem better.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot provide screenshoot of real data, as i am not authorised to display it. but i was hoping that someone with mysql experience would know the logic problem of this query without really going through real data

Comment: You should execute 2 queries - one with EN and one with DE , because what you are getting it:
Get the row from cars that ID=72727272 and source = 1.
Duplicate the rows and add parts (two languages each found part).
Then duplicated rows for language and interiors.
ETC.   that means you are not really getting what you wanted.

Comment: Something seems a little "off" about your table structure. Typically, an `id` field is a primary key (unique), which would suggest car could only join to one entry in each of the tables the follow it in the query; but allowing for multiple languages suggests the id values in those tables are not unique. Also, while a car having only one of interior, exterior, wheel (type?) makes sense; I am not sure a car with only a single "part" or "extra" does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is due to every match from parts, interior, exterior, and so on are being combined with each other regardless of `language`. You're getting every combination of the associated `de` and `en` data.

```
SELECT cars.model
FROM cars
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'en' AS language UNION SELECT 'de') AS l
LEFT JOIN parts ON parts.id = cars.partId AND parts.language = l.language
LEFT JOIN interior ON interior.id = cars.interiorId AND interior.language = l.language
LEFT JOIN exterior ON exterior.id = cars.exteriorId AND exterior.language = l.language
LEFT JOIN wheels ON wheels.id = cars.wheelId AND wheels.language = l.language
LEFT JOIN extra ON extra.id = cars.extraId AND extra.language = l.language
WHERE cars.id IN ('72727272') 
   AND cars.source = 1
```

Also, I am assuming the full query you are attempting `SELECT`s more than just `cars.model`; otherwise, all this `JOIN`ing is pointless.

Comment: this syntax is helpful and working, thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try putting join condition on language as well like below:

```
SELECT distinct cars.model
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN parts ON parts.id = cars.partId AND parts.language IN ('en', 'de')
LEFT JOIN interior ON interior.id = cars.interiorId AND interior.language =parts.language 
LEFT JOIN exterior ON exterior.id = cars.exteriorId AND exterior.language =parts.language
LEFT JOIN wheels ON wheels.id = cars.wheelId AND wheels.language =parts.language
LEFT JOIN extra ON extra.id = cars.extraId AND extra.language =parts.language
WHERE cars.id IN ('72727272') AND cars.source = 1
```

As you require result in either english or german, it will make sure only english language or german language results are joined.

Comment: If a car has no `parts`, or is lacking parts entries for a language, no entries from the tables that follow will be retrieved either.

Comment: this answer seems to be working faster then CROSS JOIN but indeed can get user in trouble in case of missing records